# How do i store finger print against database record

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin.ios

I am using touch id and it appears to work fine pushing my view in when a sucesffull fingeer print is found my question is however how do i store this against say a user record in azure so that i can do look ups on customer data what is the best way of doing this. Ie should i only the finger print reader o be active once they have signed up to app.

The following code is what I am using to catch the finger print on btn touch up inside

partial void touchId(UIButton sender)
    {

```
    //Lets double check the device supports Touch ID
    if (context.CanEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, out error))
    {
        var replyHandler = new LAContextReplyHandler((success, error) =>
            {
                InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        if (success)
                        {
                            var newVC = new UIViewController();


                    PresentViewController(newVC, true, null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var alert = new UIAlertView("OOPS!", "Something went wrong.", null, "Oops", null);
                            alert.Show();
                        }
                    });
            });
        context.EvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, "Logging in with Touch ID", replyHandler);
    }
    else
    {
        var alert = new UIAlertView("Error", "TouchID not available", null, "BOOO!", null);
        alert.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: One important thing to note: you **do not get access to any fingerprint information**! You only get a boolean wether or not the user is authenticated, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for calrifying that for me but if under apple guidlines we cannot store the device id against a user how would one identify the person loged in ?.